# Issue with paperclip, upload image

Tags: image, paperclip

I have some problem with paperclip gem. When I try add record in my app i got error : http://postimg.org/image/xy0stdctd/

When i add record without image upload, everything works great.

controller

```
def create

  @user = User.new
end

  def made
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      redirect_to(action:'index' )
    else
      render ('index')

    end
  end
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:avatar, :name)
end
```

view

```
<%= form_for :user, url: {action: 'made'}, :html => { :multipart => true } do |form| %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>

    <br>

    <%= form.file_field :avatar %>
    <br>


    <%= form.submit "dodaj" %>
<% end %>
```

in terminal I have

Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (8.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/
layout (130.0ms)
Cannot render console with content type multipart/form-dataAllowed content types: [#, #, #]